# Plotting a complicated 3D wave on the surface of a sphere

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, vector, output

Suppose you have a vectorial wave described by a complicated function of time and cartesian coordinates $t$, $x$, $y$ $z$ (very simple example below) :

```
WaveField[t_, x_, y_, z_] := 0.5{1, 0, 0}Sin[2Pi(z - t) + Pi/3] + 0.75{0, 1, 0}Sin[2Pi(x - t) + Pi/2] + 0.25{0, 0, 1}Sin[2Pi(y - t) + 2Pi/3]
```

How would you represent its "density", defined as

```
WaveDensity[t_, x_, y_, z_] := WaveField[t, x, y, z].WaveField[t, x, y, z]
```

on the surface of the unit sphere ?  Or maybe on the $x y$ plane ?

My problem is to create a kind of vizualisation of that wave, which is varying in time and space.  Drawing a vectorial 3D representation over a cubic space would be extremely messy.

Comment: You mention in your question that you would also be interested in a projection on a plane. That would probably be faster, but you lose yet another degree of freedom. Could you update your question to specify which ranges of e.g. $t$ and one of the spatial variables you would like to explore?

Comment: @MarcoB, any range would do.  Any plane would do also, since the wave is actually random.  Lets say the $x y $ plane, at $t = 0$ (or using Manipulate, like what I've shown in another answer).

Comment: @Cham Sure, added to answer. That is also almost fast enough for a regular `Manipulate`. See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 10):

It seems to me that your function depends on too many variables to be represented entirely as a 3D contour. Perhaps we can get to what you need by approximation.

To start off, here is perhaps an example of a 3D contour on the surface of the unit sphere *for a specific value of $t$* ($t=1$):

```
SliceContourPlot3D[
  WaveDensity[1, x, y, z], x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 2,
  {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 3/2],
  PlotPoints -> 75
]
```

[image: static 3D surface contour plot]

---

An animated version can be created by pre-calculating an array of `SliceContourPlot3D` objects, then using `ListAnimate`. I did the calculations using automatic parallelization, since the tasks are entirely independent and parallelize well.

```
plots = ParallelTable[
   SliceContourPlot3D[
     WaveDensity[t, x, y, z], x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1,
     {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 11/10],
     PlotPoints -> 50
   ],
   {t, 0, 1, 0.1}
 ];

ListAnimate[plots]
```

[image: Animated list of plots]

---

OP also expressed interest in a planar projection. This is much faster of course, so we can set up a `Manipulate` to explore different time points and $z$-levels:

```
Manipulate[
  ContourPlot[
    WaveDensity[t, x, y, z],
    {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
    PlotPoints -> 25
  ],
  {{t, 0}, 0, 1},
  {{z, 0}, -2, 2}
]
```

[image: 2D contours]

Comment: As the OP wants to vary time, that could be used as the variable in an animation.

Comment: @J.M. You read my mind (-: The plot is too slow for `Animate`, but I am trying to per-calculate some plots to use in a `ListAnimate`.

Comment: @MarcoB, unfortunately, my old version 7 doesn't recognize `SliceContourPlot3D `, while it knows `ContourPlot3D`.

Comment: @MarcoB, the plane version is working.  A bit slow, though.  Is this normal ?  I'll try it on my full function.  Oh, and colors aren't the same.

Comment: @MarcoB, try this : `Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[WaveDensity[t, x, y, 0], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  PlotPoints -> 25, ImageSize -> {700, 700}],
 {{t, 0, "Time"}, 0, 1, 0.01}]` It's working nicely, but the colors aren't the same as your output, and it's crude.  How to improve the rendering ?

Comment: Hmm, this method is way too slow.  Even after simplifying my wave, it's unusable.

Answer (score 7):

This uses a function that should be available to version 7,

```
ContourPlot3D[
 x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 4, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, ColorData["Rainbow"][WaveDensity[1, x, y, z]]], 
 Mesh -> None, ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 80
 ]
```

[image]

In this case the density values lie between 0 and 1 already, so there is no issue, but if they did not, you would need to use `ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[WaveDensity[1, x, y, z],{min,max}]]` where `min` and `max` are the range of values you expect the function to take on the sphere.

Comment: It's working, but it's very slow.

Comment: @Cham The plot does rotate, it's probably just awfully slow. It is quite jerky on my laptop.

Comment: It's jerky for you ?  On which version ?

Comment: Ok, I can rotate it, but it's awefully slow.  This would be horrible on my real function, which is much more complicated than the simple example I gave.

Comment: Reducing the `PlotPoints`and using a Manipulate gives some interesting results, but it's very crude, and pretty slow : `Manipulate[
 ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 4,
  {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2},
  ColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z}, 
    ColorData["Rainbow"][WaveDensity[t, x, y, z]]],
  Mesh -> None,
  Axes -> True,
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotPoints -> 30,
  SphericalRegion -> True,
  Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
  ImageSize -> {500, 500}],
 {{t, 0, "Time"}, 0, 1, 0.01}]`

Comment: What about doing something similar on a plane only ?  Lets say the $x y$ plane.