# How can I make a DensityPlot3D over a triangle?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

I know that I can plot over 3D-regions like balls via

```
DensityPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2, {x, y, z} ∈ Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1]]
```

But, not surprisingly, this breaks down for 2D-regions like triangles.

How can I create a 3D plot over surfaces to visualize the functions defined on those surfaces?

I know that there are ways to do this for Balls for example via SliceContourPlot3D (ref [Plotting a complicated 3D wave on the surface of a sphere](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110959/plotting-a-complicated-3d-wave-on-the-surface-of-a-sphere)), but I don't think this is possible in this case (and if possible, probably terribly inefficient)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't. `DensityPlot3D` will reject anything that has [`RegionDimension`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionDimension.html) not equal to 3, e.g.

```
In[91]:= RegionDimension@Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}]
(*Out[91]= 2 *)
```

Instead, you use [`SliceDensityPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceDensityPlot3D.html) with the 2D region as follows:

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2, 
 Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}], 
 {x, y, z} \[Element] Cuboid[]]
```

[image: SliceDensityPlot3D of (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 over Triangle[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}]]

**Edit:**
The symmetry of the function needs to be taken into account, though, when choosing the slice. For example, if your function is spherically symmetric, like `(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2` is, then `"CenterSphere"` is a poor choice for slice as the surface will just show numerical noise, e.g.

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2, "CenterSphere", 
 {x, y, z} \[Element] Cuboid[-{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}]]
```

[image: SliceDensityPlot3D of (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 over "CenterSphere" showing numerical noise.]

But, `"CenterCutSphere"` works very well here as the numerical noise is not visible relative to the other variations present, e.g.

```
SliceDensityPlot3D[(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2, "CenterCutSphere", 
 {x, y, z} \[Element] Cuboid[-{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}]]
```

[image: SliceDensityPlot3D of (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 over "CenterCutSphere" with the default cut-out angle of Pi/2.]

Answer (score 4):

The following works for `MeshRegions` that represent surfaces.

First, we define a function and a `MeshRegion`. For simplicity, I use a sphere. A `Triangle` is not as easy to discretize (i.e. to refine).

```
f = X \[Function] X[[1]] X[[2]];
R = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.00001];
```

Next, we generate a color gradient image with tick lines as texture:

```
colfun = ColorData["SunsetColors"];
ticks = 20;
tickthickness = 5;
spread = Round[1024/ticks];
n = (spread + tickthickness) (ticks + 1);
a = Developer`ToPackedArray[List @@@ (colfun /@ (Range[0, n]/n))];
Do[
 Do[
  a[[i + j]] = {0., 0., 0.}
  , {j, 1, tickthickness - 1}
  ]
 , {i, 1, n, spread + tickthickness}
];
tex = Image[ConstantArray[a, 15]]
```

[image]

Finally, we evaluate the function on all `MeshCoordinates`, rescale them and plot the mesh as `GraphicsComplex` with according `VertexNormals` (thanks to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162836/finding-surface-normal-for-3d-region-at-a-specific-point) post)  and with `VertexTextureCoordinates` according to the (scaled) values of `f`:

```
p = MeshCoordinates[R];
vals = Map[f, p];
Graphics3D[{
  Texture[tex], EdgeForm[],
  GraphicsComplex[
   p,
   Polygon[MeshCells[R, 2][[All, 1]]],
   VertexNormals -> Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[R, 0],
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> 
    Transpose[{Rescale[vals, {Min[vals], Max[vals]}, {0.001, 0.999}], 
      ConstantArray[0.5, Length[p]]}]
   ]
  },
 Lighting -> "Neutral"
 ]
```

This is the result of the procedure:

[image]